# Specific characters in language files in InstallShield 2015 Limited Edition

Tags: c#, localization, installshield, codepages

I have a program and I want to make a setup file for it. I would use InstallShield 2015 Limited Edition.

I want to replace the english messages during the run of the setup, but I couldn't find any way to change the code page other than 1252.

Some of the messages would contain the character 'ő', which is not available in 1252 code page.

I tried to change the project's language to any other language the program can serve, but with no avail.

I tried to change the code page in the project's isl file to 1250, unicode, utf-8, but the error message still refers to 1252 page code.

The error message by the way:
-7185: The 'whatever' translation for string identifier 'something' includes characters that are not available on code page 1250.

Has anybody met any similar problem?

Comment: I am also trying to use tick and cross mark in some text with font wingdings in a dialog in InstallShield 2016. It gives me similar error while building the release - " The translation for string identifier ID_ includes characters that are not available on code page 1252."

Comment: I followed these links but not clear what exactly would be he implications. http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/IHelpBuildErrors.htm and http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/ReleaseGridBuildTab.htm#ref-views_3665898677_buildutf-8database

Answer (score 1):

Their support said it is not available in the Limited edition. One should buy the Professional or Premier Edition to have 'ő' and its fellows.